# CLLocation Prompt shows and disappears in one moment

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, uialertcontroller, ios10

In my app I try to get longitude and latitude from GPS. To do that I have to ask user about permission to access to his location. Before I do that I add to `Info.plist` this two rulees: `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description` and `Privacy - Location Always Usage Description`, then in `AppDelegate` I ask about permission doing it (SWIFT 3.0):

```
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() == true {
        let localisationManager = CLLocationManager()
        localisationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        localisationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

I can see `UIAlertController` for one moment while running the app, but almost in this same time it disappears and I have no time to tap `Allow` and I can't use GPS. How to fix it?

> Working solution of my problem:

I created separate variables `var locationManager = CLLocationManager()` in `class LocationManager and then I used it in function.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that *localisationManager* object is being deallocated before the authorization prompt appears ... `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` runs in a deferred manner, so this instance of `CLLocationManager` get pulled out from underneath you.

So change the scope of *localisationManager* to your View Controller class instead of a local variable.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 let localisationManager = CLLocationManager()    // <-- scope to class

 //...
 function requestAuthorization() {
   localisationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() 
 }

}
```

You could alternatively scope the *CLLocationManager* to your app delegate.

This is explained nicely in the **WWDC 2016** video **Core Location Best Practices** near minute 21 of the session.

Comment: Just an extra, here is the video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/716/