# How to get filtered compass heading value from CLLocationManager?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation, kalman-filter

My app needs present smooth heading value on a heading tap on the screen.

However, the heading value I got like below list:

```
275.134063720703
275.557250976562
275.518890380859
272.912872314453
269.957977294922
273.501312255859
272.390350341797
273.241363525391
275.250274658203
272.976440429688
273.790771484375
272.344940185547
272.824005126953
276.205505371094
272.190979003906
273.337341308594
274.798583984375
275.545501708984
272.631317138672
274.248596191406
273.635284423828
273.342041015625
275.216186523438
```

Even the iPhone was laying on the table.

I assume I need a filter work with Gyro to make compass heading stable.

My question is: Is there any existing method or lab to get more stable and accurate heading? If no, do you have any suggestion if I write it by my own?

Answer (score 0):

Reason: **Forgot request CoreLocation permission**

After a half day diagnosing, finally, I found the reason of I got inaccurate compass heading is I haven't request CoreLocation permission yet.

The problem is I have never received any alert message about that. The CLLocationManager just keep feed me data.

Solution:
Just ask the user to grant permission: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38465537/2073991